# SSIS For each loop, merge value from another datasource without a lookup

Tags: ssis

The scenario is that we have a list of records that we want to insert into our ERP. Before we do any insertion, we need to request the next number sequence from the ERP for each new record we plan to insert. So the logic is:

- Grab all new records ready to insert.
- Use a foreach loop to iterate through these records.
- For new insertions, request a number sequence from the ERP. This is a single column with e.g. RecordIndex as the column name.
- Insert the record into the ERP, with RecordIndex as a value.

There is no matching that needs to occur between the row and the index; the index is generated on the fly specific for this row. The problem is merge, etc. seems to require a value to correlate the RecordIndex with the new row but we just want to add this value as a column irrespective of anything else.

Comment: Hi @Edward can you please provide an example with data explained in each step ?

Comment: It sounds like the record index should just be the identity of the column and have it auto increment, but if you can
 post your database technology and some code that could help.